piklab-prog "Failed to set port mode to U"
I've had a hard-drive crash in an old production system, and I'm trying to move stuff to "new" WinXP machine.  One of the things that's not working is piklab-prog (0.15.8), used in scripts to program Microchip PIC products.
With this command line:
piklab-prog -d 16&946 -p icd2 -t COM1 -c program file.hex

I get the response:
error: Failed to set port mode to 'U'

The message is a bit misleading: unable to set port mode 'U' actually means unable to set device mode to 'U', and it may be a timing problem.
In the connection sequence, MPLAB sends the Character 'U', and gets the response 'u'. piclab-prog sends the same 'U', and gets the response 0x03.
(port settings are identical, it doesn't appear to be an unflushed character, FIFO settings don't help).
piklab was a well known and popular tool 20 years ago, now, not so much.  Any solutions?

this kind of programmer ? http://www.madlab.org/piclab/

-p  icd2 (*piKlab

Ok. Noted the "K". You should use PICkit 1...5 depending of your windows system.

I guess ICD2 (pretty old!!) is not supported by your windows. https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/ICD2-Obsolete-tool#:~:text=Why%20is%20the%20ICD2%20programmer%2Fdebugger%20not%20connecting%20to%20the%20PC%3F&text=Please%20be%20aware%20ICD2%20and,%2C%20such%20as%20ICD4%2FPICkit4.

WinXP is the version of Windows that the ICD2 drivers were built for.

Which MPLABX version are you using?

This is an ICD2 on WinXP. MPLABX doesn't have a CLI tool for ICD2. I'm trying use piklab-prog as I was on the old XP machine. because (1) that's what we were using, and (2) MPLABX doesn't have a CLI tool for ICD2.
